# String.fromCharCode and String.fromCodePoint are not working in react native app's apk

Tags: ecmascript-6, ascii, react-native

String.fromCharCode and String.fromCodePoint both are working fine in chrome developer tools and in the emulator but when i am generating the apk and running it on the actual android device, its not working.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN's String.fromCodePoint doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint):

> The String.fromCodePoint method has been added to ECMAScript 2015 and may not be supported in all web browsers or environments yet. Use the code below for a polyfill:
>
> ```
> *! http://mths.be/fromcodepoint v0.1.0 by @mathias */
> if (!String.fromCodePoint) {
>   (function() {
>     var defineProperty = (function() {
>       // IE 8 only supports `Object.defineProperty` on DOM elements
>       try {
>         var object = {};
>         var $defineProperty = Object.defineProperty;
>         var result = $defineProperty(object, object, object) && $defineProperty;
>       } catch(error) {}
>       return result;
>     }());
>     var stringFromCharCode = String.fromCharCode;
>     var floor = Math.floor;
>     var fromCodePoint = function() {
>       var MAX_SIZE = 0x4000;
>       var codeUnits = [];
>       var highSurrogate;
>       var lowSurrogate;
>       var index = -1;
>       var length = arguments.length;
>       if (!length) {
>         return '';
>       }
>       var result = '';
>       while (++index < length) {
>         var codePoint = Number(arguments[index]);
>         if (
>           !isFinite(codePoint) ||       // `NaN`, `+Infinity`, or `-Infinity`
>           codePoint < 0 ||              // not a valid Unicode code point
>           codePoint > 0x10FFFF ||       // not a valid Unicode code point
>           floor(codePoint) != codePoint // not an integer
>         ) {
>           throw RangeError('Invalid code point: ' + codePoint);
>         }
>         if (codePoint <= 0xFFFF) { // BMP code point
>           codeUnits.push(codePoint);
>         } else { // Astral code point; split in surrogate halves
>           // http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding#surrogate-formulae
>           codePoint -= 0x10000;
>           highSurrogate = (codePoint >> 10) + 0xD800;
>           lowSurrogate = (codePoint % 0x400) + 0xDC00;
>           codeUnits.push(highSurrogate, lowSurrogate);
>         }
>         if (index + 1 == length || codeUnits.length > MAX_SIZE) {
>           result += stringFromCharCode.apply(null, codeUnits);
>           codeUnits.length = 0;
>         }
>       }
>       return result;
>     };
>     if (defineProperty) {
>       defineProperty(String, 'fromCodePoint', {
>         'value': fromCodePoint,
>         'configurable': true,
>         'writable': true
>       });
>     } else {
>       String.fromCodePoint = fromCodePoint;
>     }
>   }());
> }
> ```

so you can try to polyfill `String.fromCodePoint` in your file

Comment: But isn't React Native supposed to provide ES6 via Babel transpilation?

Comment: I lost a whole week trying to understand why my App was broken in production until I found the reason and it was this one. What's the biggest Java / android failure (even in Android 7.0 has not been implemented)